# Bessel function values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Given

> $$J_m(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{(-1)^n}\over{n!(n+m)!}}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{m+2n},$$ where $m=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $x\ge0$.

Need to show $$\left|J_m(x)\right|\le1.$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you're allowed to, but using that $$J_m(x)=\frac 1 \pi\int_0^\pi \cos(mt-x\sin t)dt$$

does the job.

Comment: That does it. It doesn't seem to hard to verify that the series comes from this formula.
$$
J_m^{(k)}(0) = \frac{\color{#C00000}{(-1)^{k(k-1)/2}}}{\pi} \int_0^\pi\sin^k(t)\left[\color{#00A000}{\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}}\cos(mt) + \color{#00A000}{\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}}\sin(mt)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
where the red part is $\pm1$ and the green part is $0$ or $1$.